# Combine and append elements in List<string> C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

I have a List of strings

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

myList.Add(string1_1);
myList.Add(string1_2);
myList.Add(string2_1);
myList.Add(string2_2);
myList.Add(string3_1);
myList.Add(string3_2);
```

Now, after some magic, I want to combine the elements of the List, making them like this

```
myList[0] = string1_1 + string1_2
myList[1] = string2_1 + string2_2
myList[2] = string3_1 + string3_2
```

thus also cutting the size of the List in half. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple for loop would work:

```
List<string> inputList = new List<string>();
List<string> outputList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < inputList.Count; i += 2) // assumes an even number of elements
{
    if (i == inputList.Count - 1)
        outputList.Add(inputList[i]); // add single value
        // OR use the continue or break keyword to do nothing if you want to ignore the uneven value.
    else
        outputList.Add(inputList[i] + inputList[i+1]); // add two values as a concatenated string
}
```

For loops are good for looping and dealing with pairs or triplets of elements at a time.

Comment: LINQ is supposed to make things easier to read and more succinct, not more confusing and verbose.

Comment: You may as well add the check for when i == inputList.Count - 1 and only add inputList[i] if so. But who knows if that would be acceptable for the OP's scenario...

Comment: @Xiaofu Yeah I'm assuming by his question that he can make assumptions about having an even list with his data.  And you're right, we can't decide whether his business logic should ignore an odd value or simply append it to the list.

Comment: @Flea777 It's not about the number of lines, it's about *readability*. What is most maintainable?

Comment: @Flea777 Well his inputList is already declared, I just put it there for completeness which you ignored.  And the braces are optional.  It's actually only 3 lines of code.  It's actually fewer *characters*.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Could you make it so that it can take odd numbers of strings as well?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen Sure just make sure to modify it in your case to handle what's logical for your application.  You might want to throw a meaningful error or warn the user if the input data is bad, or just ignore the extra data, or append it without concatenating it, or save it for later and merge it with the next set of data.  Your example is very abstract so not all solutions may be right for you.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Thanks. I need to be able to do both situations since the data is arbitrary. I added a check for odd numbered list and this works. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I would definitely go with a `for` loop approach provided by Trevor, but if you'd like to do it using LINQ you can use `GroupBy` and `string.Join`:

```
myList = myList.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
               .GroupBy(x => x.i / 2)
               .Select(g => string.Join("", g.Select(x => x.x)))
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var half = myList
           .Select((s,idx) => s + (idx < myList.Count() - 1 ? myList[idx +1] : string.Empty) )
           .Where((s,idx) => idx % 2 == 0)
           .ToList();
```

You can do a projection of all items in the form string[i] + string[i+1] (being careful to check that the string[i+1] element exists):

```
.Select((s,idx) => s + (idx < myList.Count() - 1 ? myList[idx +1] : string.Empty) )
```

Then filter only the even elements:

```
.Where((s,idx) => idx % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: Wow, this is hard to read... Care to explain it in more detail?

Comment: Of course. At first do a projection to join every pair of items. Then filter only the odd items.

Comment: There is an `edit` button to the left bottom of your answer. Might I suggest that you add that explanation to your answer instead of in a comment?

Comment: I would love a better elaboration of this and how it works. Also, please use the more popular form of `if`-sentences. Those you use really confuses me